# Should I have a break between rooms when installing laminate flooring?

Tags: flooring, installation, laminate-floor

I'm going to be putting in laminate flooring in my basement on top of a concrete slab. The basement consists of two rooms, the boards will be running perpendicular to the wall with the door between them so there's no natural door threshold there. Should I put in a break between them with a transition piece, or can I make it all one "floor"? The total run at that point would be about 34 feet.

Comment: Possible Duplicate [Should I run laminate continuously through rooms, or separate with T moulding?](http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/18734/should-i-run-laminate-continuously-through-rooms-or-separate-with-t-moulding)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to "should I put a break between them" implies there is a right or wrong way.

There isn't.

You can do it however you prefer.

Comment: My apologies - the question probably should have been phrased "is there an installation/maintenance reason to do it one way or the other?" I'll probably just make it one floor, since I think I'll like having the continuity between them more than having a break.

Answer (score 1):

Technically speaking there is no right or wrong way to do it. Personal preference prevails. But generally you shouldn't break it unless you have some reason to do so. Superfluous breaks between doors is tacky in my opinion and unprofessional.

Breaking it up might make it slightly easier on you when installing it. Which is why a lot of people do it. But it's worth a bit of "extra" work to have a nice clean continuous floor throughout.